# Disco Diffusion v5.61 Locally - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvidia-smi'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm new to Disco Diffusion, and somewhat new to Python and Google Colab. I used it a few times years ago (Python and Google Colab) for a machine learning class at my university, but that's about it.

Anyways, I'm trying to run Disco Diffusion v5.61 locally, and running into this error here:
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvidia-smi'".

I have connected Google Colab to a "local runtime" and using Ubuntu with Jupyter Notebook to serve a backend url with my access token. There seems to be no errors when connecting to my local runtime, but for some reason Google Colab can't find my gpu it seems?

Again, new to this, so any help would appreciated! Thanks!

Things I have tried:

Changing my settings in Google Colab (Edit->Notebook settings->Hardware accelerator) to None and GPU.

Running a different command to get the backend url up - the one that seems to work without any errors is this:jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' 
--port=8888 --no-browser

Answer (score 0):

might help somebody else, but to me it helped to change the settings in Google Colab (Edit->Notebook settings->Hardware accelerator) to None to GPU, as you said in the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34535778)

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with using GPU on Colab.
so You must change Colab's runtime. (Runtime -> change runtime type) or you must upgrade your plan (purchase Colab plus or Colab pro)